# Having "border-radius: 100%;" as an IDEAL circle when font size changes

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/x7zustcb/) is the JSFiddle with a circle (made with **border-radius: 100%;**) highlighted in red.
 Font size is adaptive to viewport width. When viewport is wide enough the circle looks ideal, but as the viewport width *dicreases* the circle vertically flattens.
Is there a way to *always* keep the circle ideal?
Here is the code:

```
<div class="meaning">
<ol class="circle">
<li>Text_1</li>
</ol>
</div>

.meanings_and_examples {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.meaning {
width: auto;
text-align: left;
color: #1f2c60;
font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
}

ol.circle {
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 3em;
margin-left: 1vw;
border: 2px solid purple;
}

li {
line-height: calc(1em + 1.5vw);
}

ol.circle > li {
position: relative;
counter-increment: item;
margin-top: 1.5%;
border: 2px solid orange;
}

ol.circle > li::before {
position: absolute;
transform: translateX(-150%);
content: counter(item);
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 100%;
width: calc(1.1em + 1.5vw);
background: #1f2c60;
color: white;
border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: If you want a circle you have to start with a square

Comment: I had a look at the fiddle but couldn't seem to make " the circle vertically flattens." - could you provide 1) a width/height (in px) where the circle is "Ideal" as reference and 2) a width/height (in px) where the circle is not "Ideal" - 

Also if you are finding that this is only happening in specific viewports, have you considered adding in meda quieries to hard code the syles

Comment: @Wally JSFiddle shows the viewport width in pixels, so you can use the link from my initial post to play with preview window size. When the width is 1000px the circle looks great, but when it's decreased to 200px, the circle flattens. This happens on both - my PC and Android device. Both use Chromium-based Opera browser. Can you see that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, You  have three options:

1. SVG way: draw the circle via svg, but you need to put a number in the circle. Then You can use  svg::before or ::after and z-index.
   [SVG circle](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp)
2. Draw a square via CSS and set border-radius: 50%;. Higher value won't work. Here is an example: [try me][2]
3. Using UTF-8 Geometric Shapes " &#9675 "
   [instructions](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp)

I suppose, the second option would be the best choice in your case.

```
  [2]: https://codepen.io/juricon/pen/eYmRVPQ
```

Comment: Privet, @Yuriy Ivanochko  2nd method worked perfectly alright, thank you! However there's a small problem with vertical alignement of items - have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/h3yswep8/   I want red-bordered item to be vertically aligned vs. orange-bordered one. And the number _inside_ the blue circle to be vertically in the middle of the circle (horizontally - it _already_ is). I reduced circle's border radius to 10% to better see (un)alignement. Is the above-said possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [solution][1] of the second task. Don't forget that you can't move red bordered circle without number in it, because it's one object. You have to add additional tag and use position: absolute for it + z-index.

Also, could you draw and show info about "I want red-bordered item to be vertically aligned vs. orange-bordered one." I didn't understand it. Do you want to achieve this one:

P.S.: Actually, you will find the solution for all your tasks in codepen link. Also, I guess, there is another way to do all those things via flex-box.

"

(1) 
Almost circle :) Text_1

(2)
 Text_2

"

```
   [1]: https://codepen.io/juricon/pen/vYEZbbG
```

Comment: Thank you, @Yuriy Ivanochko  Could you please have a look at this code https://jsfiddle.net/4nqbmh5t/  - few modifications which i've highlighted in the first comment.